# Concat QML Properties with Javascript

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I'm setting properties on QML items with java script, where "gaugetext" is a property of my QML object.

```
    function finishCreation(setWidth,setHeight,setX,setY,setMinValue,setMaxValue,setDecPlace,setUnit,setID,SetValueObject,SetValueProperty) {
    ...
        "gaugetext": Qt.binding(function(){return SetValueObject[SetValueProperty] +  " " + setUnit})
....
}
```

This works well, but I want to set numbers of decimals. So I tried this:

```
"gaugetext": Qt.binding(function(){return "(" + SetValueObject[SetValueProperty]+ ")" + ".toFixed(" + setDecPlace + ")" + " " + setUnit})
```

But this results that the correct Value is shown with ".toFixed(value)".

Comment: Two questions. First: What do you try to achive? Second: (out of curiosity) Why do you try to do that with JS?

Comment: I'm creating qml objects (gauges) in runtime for a car dashboard software. The dashboard has to be dynamical, so the user can create gauges in runtime. It's working, I have just problems with the toFixed function.I thought JS is the best solution for the creation of objects in runtime,.

Answer (score 0):

You return a String `"(<someValue>).toFixed(<someOtherValue>) <someThirdValue>"`.

You probably want to omit some of your `"` since you probably want to have the pieces that you mark as string to be executed instead.

```
return SetValueObject[SetValueProperty].toFixed(setDecPlace) + " " + setUnit
```

*~~~(untetested)*

Most likely however using a "finalize creation" function is a bad approach.

Comment: i tried this also, but it returns in console TypeError: Cannot call method 'toFixed' of undefined

Comment: Then `SetValueObject[SetValueProperty]` is undefined. It seems `SetValueProperty` is no valid key.